# How do I yank to Clipboard in Sublime text using VIM-like `yX` keyboard combinations

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, clipboard

I got used to having VIM configured so all the `yX` combinations (`yy`, `y$`, etc.) also copy to the system clipboard.

I haven't found the way to do the same in Sublime Text 3. I miss the configuration, and I may many mistakes while not having it.

Comment: What package are you using to provide `vim` support in Sublime?

Comment: @OdatNurd I'm using Vintage Mode